# How to watch for variable changes in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a view which has a property called `headerClass` which I define at the top of the view and in various methods I change the value by doing `this.headerClass = 'new value'`.

But how can I watch for changes to this variable?  I tried add `this.headerClass.on("change", this.render, this);` but I get an error when doing this.

Below is my code

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".header"),
    template: _.template($("#header-template").html()),
    headerClass: 'normal',

    initialize: function () {
        this.render();

        //This doesn't seem to work
        this.headerClass.on("change", this.render, this);
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template({headerClass: this.headerClass}));
        return this;
    },

    changeClass: function () {
        //When the value changes I want to re-render the view
        this.headerClass: 'fluid';
    }
});
```

Comment: You can setup a custom listener to the view, and then trigger it when changing the header. another option it to attach a model to the view and listen to it's changes...

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is just a copy/paste error, but you have a problem in your `changeClass` function when setting the value of `headerClass`. You should be using an equals operator and not a colon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest implementing a sort of `setter` function for this attribute. Every time this function is called with a new value, an event is triggered by the view.

```
set_headerClass: function (value) {
    this.headerClass = value;
    this.trigger("changed:headerClass");
}
```

You can now add a listener to the view and watch for changes:

```
initialize: function () {
    ...
    // Will re-render the view when the event is detected.
    this.on("changed:headerClass", this.render, this);
},
```

When you want to change the `headerClass` value, you would do so by calling the setter function:

```
changeClass: function () {
    this.set_headerClass('fluid');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger an event when the value is changed

```
 this.on('headerClassChanged', this.render);


  this.trigger('headerClassChanged');
```

Comment: You're on the right track! However the problem here is to know *when* to trigger the event - this is what the OP is actually asking - how to know when the attribute has been changed.

Comment: sorry i thought that the headerClass is a DOM element , i've updated my answer